# Weather app which asking locaton does not work after click "block"

Tags: javascript

I have created weather app which asks "allow" or "block" location. when i click "allow" everything works fine, when click "block" it does not get my location, its good, but after reload website my weather does not ask location again, it's title "user denied location". i want to work my weather after reload again.  please help me.

here is my javascript code

```
  const iconElement = document.querySelector(".weather-icon");
  const tempElement = document.querySelector(".temperature-value p");
  const descElement = document.querySelector(".temperature-description p");
  const locationElement = document.querySelector(".location p");
  const notificationElement = document.querySelector(".notification");

  // App data
  const weather = {};

  weather.temperature = {
      unit : "celsius"
  }

  // APP CONSTS AND VARS
  const KELVIN = 273;
  // API KEY
  const key = "82005d27a116c2880c8f0fcb866998a0";

  // CHECK IF BROWSER SUPPORTS GEOLOCATION
  if('geolocation' in navigator){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setPosition, showError);
  }else{
      notificationElement.style.display = "block";
      notificationElement.innerHTML = "<p>Browser doesn't Support Geolocation</p>";
  }

  // SET USER'S POSITION
  function setPosition(position){
      let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      let longitude = position.coords.longitude;

      getWeather(latitude, longitude);
  }

  // SHOW ERROR WHEN THERE IS AN ISSUE WITH GEOLOCATION SERVICE
  function showError(error){
      notificationElement.style.display = "block";
      notificationElement.innerHTML = `<p> ${error.message} </p>`;
  }

  // GET WEATHER FROM API PROVIDER
  function getWeather(latitude, longitude){
      let api = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${key}`;

      fetch(api)
          .then(function(response){
              let data = response.json();
              return data;
          })
          .then(function(data){
              weather.temperature.value = Math.floor(data.main.temp - KELVIN);
              weather.description = data.weather[0].description;
              weather.iconId = data.weather[0].icon;
              weather.city = data.name;
              weather.country = data.sys.country;
          })
          .then(function(){
              displayWeather();
          });
  }

  // DISPLAY WEATHER TO UI
  function displayWeather(){
      iconElement.innerHTML = `<img src="icons/${weather.iconId}.png"/>`;
      tempElement.innerHTML = `${weather.temperature.value}°<span>C</span>`;
      descElement.innerHTML = weather.description;
      locationElement.innerHTML = `${weather.city}, ${weather.country}`;
  }

  // C to F conversion
  function celsiusToFahrenheit(temperature){
      return (temperature * 9/5) + 32;
  }

  // WHEN THE USER CLICKS ON THE TEMPERATURE ELEMENET
  tempElement.addEventListener("click", function(){
      if(weather.temperature.value === undefined) return;

      if(weather.temperature.unit == "celsius"){
          let fahrenheit = celsiusToFahrenheit(weather.temperature.value);
          fahrenheit = Math.floor(fahrenheit);

          tempElement.innerHTML = `${fahrenheit}°<span>F</span>`;
          weather.temperature.unit = "fahrenheit";
      }else{
          tempElement.innerHTML = `${weather.temperature.value}°<span>C</span>`;
          weather.temperature.unit = "celsius"
      }
  });
```

and html code

```
 <div class="container">
            <div class="app-title">
                <p>Weather</p>
            </div>
            <div class="notification"> </div>
            <div class="weather-container">
                <div class="weather-icon">
                    <img src="icons/unknown.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="temperature-value">
                    <p>- °<span>C</span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="temperature-description">
                    <p> - </p>
                </div>
                <div class="location">
                    <p>-</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```